# What's the translation of "heckler" in French?

Tags: traduction

A heckler [is a](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=heckler&op=translate):

> a person who interrupts a performer or public speaker with derisive or aggressive comments or abuse.

What's the translation of "heckler" in French?

My attempts:

- chahuteur: doesn't convey the speech sid: it focuses more on the noisy side.
- interpellateur: doesn't convey the derisive or aggressive side.
- siffleur: doesn't convey the speech side.

Does a more faithful translation exist?

Comment: A heckler does not necessarily involve speech. You can heckle people by just making unpleasant noises.....The Larousse says this: élément pertubateur https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/perturbateur/59843

Comment: @Lambie The Larousse online [translates](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/heckler/585965) with one of the items from OP's, _chahuteur_. Your comment made it sound as if Larousse was using _élément perturbateur_. Nevertheless the entry you provide contains _agitateur_ which might be useful. An answer?

Comment: I did not use its translation function. I looked up **pertubateur**: Qui perturbe l'organisation, le fonctionnement ou l'ordre de quelque chose : Expulser les éléments perturbateurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know a word with such a precise meaning but what would be used at least in France to describe such an attitude would be *un **[emmerdeur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/emmerdeur)*** (or *une emmerdeuse* if it happens to be a woman).

It is colloquial. If you want a formal word, you can use ***[importun](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/importun)***.